# Entity Framework Core Get related data without nesting

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there a way using Entity Framework Core to get nested data without having to iterate through it? like a simple SQL select with joins i would like to show all data on the same table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you know the SQL you need to get the data you want.  So I suggest you create a database view and then map your ef entity to that.  As long as you are just reading ef will treat the view just like it would any other table.

Comment: Ah I see, i forgot you can map to views, this is probably the way to go

Answer (score 1):

I think youre looking for `.Include()` and `.ThenInclude()` methods that allow you to load related data in a *eager way*.

More on that topic on the official entity framework documentation at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: but this still keeps data separated by navigation properties that i have to iterate through. Maybe i wasn't clear enough, the intended result is to loop through all data on a table in a view with a single foreach. I tried getting data from the lowest child so i could get the parents data. Problem with this method is that i cannot get the parent data if child data is null

Comment: When this is applied on an IQueryable<T> for a type K which T has a navigation property to, efcore translates that to a LEFT JOIN query when you enumerate the results of the IQueryable with .ToList() for example. So no need to make foreach. I’m not sure what are you trying, please post your actual problem not the solution you’ve come up with